# zeromq high latency in multiprocessor multicore server

Tags: zeromq, latency, low-latency

Running latency test provided in perf/*_lat on single processor and mutiprocessor server showing a huge variance in latency figures.

16 cpu machine
./remote_lat tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 30 1000

```
message size: 30 [B]
roundtrip count: 1000
average latency: 97.219 [us]
```

single cpu machine
/remote_lat tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 30 1000

```
message size: 30 [B]
roundtrip count: 1000
average latency: 27.195 [us]
```

Running both the processes in the same machine.

Using libzmq 4.2.5

update:

my laptop 
intel core i5 7th generation

16 cpu server

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.30GHz

Comment: what are the specifications of each server?

Comment: @JamesHarvey added configuration details